# Partial file lines replace in linux

Tags: linux, awk, grep, cat, xargs

I have a file containing some lines 
Example:

```
Line 1 , @A11 @A21 @A31
Line 2 , @A12 @A22 @A32
Line 3 , @A13 @A23 @A33
```

I have other files which lines might contain some of the lines in the above example, like:

```
skip('Line X , @B11 @B21 @B31');
 code { ... }
skip('Line 1 , @A11 @A21 @A31');
 code { ... }
skip('Line Z , @C11 @C21 @C31');
 code { ... }
```

I want to be able to read all the lines from the first file and whenever I match line from the second example to replace 'skip(' with 'run('.
So line two from the second example should become

```
run('Line 1 , @A11 @A21 @A31');
```

Comment: On SO we do encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so please do add the same in your post and let us know then.

Comment: My answer is ready, once you add your efforts I will post mine answer :)